# Would a carriage return ^M in SSH key make a difference?

Tags: ssh, vim

I cloned a git repo to a server that had same files scattered in different places. Then I compared two directories (cloned one to existing one) to make sure that they were exactly the same. The `comp` command showed that there is only one difference and that is in an ssh key on the remote server files. There is carriage return `^M` present in the remote file. Would that change the key? If yes, how can I remove the carriage return in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No carriage returns are allowed so use substitution to remove them:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

Don't just copy the above; to insert the *control character* `^M` you have to press Ctrl+V and then Ctrl+M (otherwise if you copy-paste you will just insert the *two characters* ^M and you will get `Pattern not found`).

If the whole file instead was recognized as `dos` type, the following would also work:

```
:wq ++ff=unix
```

(change `fileformat` to unix, save and quit).